# How to Correctly Check if a Process is running and Stop it

Tags: powershell

What is the correct way of determining if a process is running, for example FireFox, and stopping it?

I did some looking around and the best way I found was this:

```
if((get-process "firefox" -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null){ 
        echo "Not Running" 
}

else{ 
    echo "Running"
    Stop-Process -processname "firefox"
 }
```

Is this the ideal way of doing it? If not, what the correct way of doing so?

Comment: Yes it does, but I wanted to know if it is the ideal way of doing it? Is their a better way? Are their any disadvantages/advantages of doing this way?

Comment: I would think a kinder way to do it would be to get the main hwnd of the firefox window, and send it a WM_CLOSE and/or WM_QUIT. That may be beyond the scope of what powershell is capable of.

Comment: If you can, could you provide an example?

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14445452/656243

Comment: If that answer completely provides a solution, let me know, and I'll mark this one as a dup.

Comment: The way I did it above, would it be incorrect and not ideal?

Comment: It's not going to give the app a chance to exit cleanly. From the docs: `Stops the specified processes without prompting for confirmation.` It's effectively killing it. Sending it a WM_CLOSE is how most application will naturally exit themselves.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The way you're doing it you're querying for the process twice. Also Lynn raises a good point about being nice first. I'd probably try something like the following:

```
# get Firefox process
$firefox = Get-Process firefox
if ($firefox) {
  # try gracefully first
  $firefox.CloseMainThread()
  # kill after five seconds
  Sleep 5
  if (!$firefox.started) {
    $firefox | Stop-Process -Force
  }
}
Remove-Variable firefox
```

Comment: Charles - this is EXACTLY what you need. Note Joey's use of the [CloseMainWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Read the docs on that MSDN page. His script tries to ask the app to exit nicely... then attempts a kill. Very nice, Joey: +1.

Comment: I was just about to say, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield Yep, I'd mark this as the answer. And, you already have.

Comment: Querying for the process twice is faster than waiting a guaranteed 5 seconds every time. But I guess if you're in no rush, you can be "nice".

Comment: @campbell.rw: Querying for the process only once avoids a race when the process doesn't exist anymore when you call `Stop-Process` (which does nothing on an exited process object, but throws an error on a non-existent process name). As for niceness, Firefox can take an awful long time to shut down sometimes, although it has gotten better. They should probably use a timeout that makes sense to them; this was just an example.

Comment: $firefox.CloseMainWindow() fails if there is more then one process. without it script is working for any number of processes

Comment: This is the part that was missing in my script to automatically close the game of my son, when playing more than 2 hours :). Thx

Answer (score 22):

If you don't need to display exact result "running" / "not runnuning", you could simply:

```
ps notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | kill -PassThru
```

If the process was not running, you'll get no results. If it was running, you'll receive `get-process` output, and the process will be stopped.

Comment: For the newbie like myself, in full  

`Get-Process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -PassThru`

Answer (score 5):

@jmp242 - the generic `System.Object` type does not contain the `CloseMainWindow` method, but statically casting the `System.Diagnostics.Process` type when collecting the `ProcessList` variable works for me.  Updated code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39773165/7404943)) with this casting (and looping changed to use `ForEach-Object`) is below.

```
function Stop-Processes {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $processName,
                                     $timeout = 5
    )
    [System.Diagnostics.Process[]]$processList = Get-Process $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    ForEach ($Process in $processList) {
        # Try gracefully first
        $Process.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null
    }

    # Check the 'HasExited' property for each process
    for ($i = 0 ; $i -le $timeout; $i++) {
        $AllHaveExited = $True
        $processList | ForEach-Object {
            If (-NOT $_.HasExited) {
                $AllHaveExited = $False
            }                    
        }
        If ($AllHaveExited -eq $true){
            Return
        }
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
    # If graceful close has failed, loop through 'Stop-Process'
    $processList | ForEach-Object {
        If (Get-Process -ID $_.ID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            Stop-Process -Id $_.ID -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Joey. It's what I am looking for.

I just bring some improvements:

- to take into account multiple processes
- to avoid reaching the timeout when all processes have terminated
- to package the whole in a function

---

```
function Stop-Processes {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $processName,
                                     $timeout = 5
    )
    $processList = Get-Process $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($processList) {
        # Try gracefully first
        $processList.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null

        # Wait until all processes have terminated or until timeout
        for ($i = 0 ; $i -le $timeout; $i ++){
            $AllHaveExited = $True
            $processList | % {
                $process = $_
                If (!$process.HasExited){
                    $AllHaveExited = $False
                }                    
            }
            If ($AllHaveExited){
                Return
            }
            sleep 1
        }
        # Else: kill
        $processList | Stop-Process -Force        
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem with this is you can end up in a state where you get
ERROR: Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'CloseMainWindow'.
but the  $processList | Stop-Process -Force   works. Not sure how to properly handle that error.

Answer (score 2):

To start with process-killing, here `python`, my 2 cents:

```
Get-Process python3.9|Stop-Process
```