# check if a process is running in windows and kill the process using Shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins

I want to check if execel.exe is running on windows, then kill it.

here how I check if the process is running:

```
tasklist | findstr /I excel
```

how can I write a shell script to check if it's running, then kill it, else do sth else

```
if tasklist | findstr /I excel
   taskkill /F /IM excel
else
   ...
fi
```

I am trying for notepad here:

```
tasklist | findstr /I notepad++.exe
if [ -z "tasklist | findstr /I notepad++.exe" ] || [ echo "Empty" ];then
    echo "The process is not running";
else
    echo "The process is running";
    taskkill /F /IM notepad++.exe;
fi
```

The problem is that if the process i not running I get an error. but if the process is running everything works fine.

Comment: Checkout @joey answer in this post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481811/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-process-is-running-and-stop-it> and see if it works for you

Comment: I have problem writing the correct syntyx.